# Entries field: Output entries related to category

Tags: categories, entries-field

I have an entries field (`activityPicker`) that links to other entries in a different section. These other entries have categories (`things-to-do` and `things-to-eat`), and I'm trying to figure out how to filter these entries by categories.

My first instinct was to do something similar to this:

```
{# Categories #}
{% set CatToDo = craft.categories.slug('things-to-do') %}
{% set CatToEat = craft.categories.slug('things-to-eat') %}

{# Entries #}    
{% set toDo = entry.activityPicker.relatedTo(catToDo) %}
{% set toEat = entry.activityPicker.relatedTo(catToEat) %}

{# Output #}
{% for item in toDo %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in toEat %}
   {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```

however that didn't work so I tried playing with `targetElement` and `sourceElement` in the `relatedTo` parameter:

```
{% set toEat = entry.activityPicker.relatedTo({
   targetElement: catToEat
}) %}

[...]
```

but this still doesn't work. Basically I get that `entry.activityPicker` returns an array of posts, but I haven't figured out how to filter those posts in a meaningful way before they hit the template.

Answer (score 1):

The `targetElement` and `sourceElement` take either an ID, an Element Model, or an array of either.

So, in your example, you'd want to do:

```
{# Categories #}
{% set CatToDo = craft.categories.slug('things-to-do').first %}
{% set CatToEat = craft.categories.slug('things-to-eat').first %}

{% set toEat = craft.entries.section('yourSection').relatedTo({
   targetElement: CatToEat,
   field: 'activityPicker'
}) %}

[...]
```

Notice the **.first** in there as the difference. You will only want the one category since you're passing the slug.

Note: This assumes that `CatToEat` is indeed the targetElement. See here for more information: http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param

Comment: Thanks Peter, however that still didn't work out as it returned all entries regardless of whether they were selected or not. I'm going down another root, which is to "deconstruct" the entries field and add an `and` criteria to the `relatedTo` param. Works well however i'm having trouble with the `sortOrder`: 
    {% set entriesDo = craft.entries({
    relatedTo: ['and',
    { sourceElement: entry, field: "activityPicker" },
    { targetElement: catDo }
    ],
    order: "sortOrder",
    limit: null
    }) %}